# The method 'startsWith' isn't defined for the class 'RadioButtonGroup'

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-group

i am making an searchdelegate of a radio buttons  so user can select one thing but i m getting this error 
"The method 'startsWith' isn't defined for the class 'RadioButtonGroup'"

`@override
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? recent
        : list.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
            ),
        itemCount: suggestionList.length);
  }`

````
    RadioButtonGroup(
       labels: <String>[
         'Criceket',
         'Swimming',
         'Running',
         'Basketball',
         'Marathon',
         'Football',
         'Baseball',
       ],

    ),
  ];```
````

Answer (score 0):

As per the given details in question.

> list.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();

It seems `p` is an instance of `RadioButtonGroup` widget and not a `String`.
That is what the exception message is trying to say:

```
The method 'startsWith' isn't defined for the class 'RadioButtonGroup'
```

Please give more detail on what is `list`'s content or what data it holds.
Also, if possible provide full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: i already provided the the list . i created a list of string before and change it later with radiobuttongroup list i think p is for the previous list not for the radiobuttongroup that's it